# XAML - MediaElement isn't playing my music

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So my *MediaElement* isn't playing my WAV file.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="bgMusic" Visibility="Hidden" Source="sounds/MainMenuSong.wav" LoadedBehavior="Manual"/>
```

Sadly I can't add a screenshot yet but here is how I have my current Solution Explorer:

- My project

  - sounds

    - MainMenuSong.wav

Here's my C# code:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
        ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanMinimize;
        optionsMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        ckbMusic.IsChecked = true;
        ckbSound.IsChecked = true;
        universalDatatypes.universalDatatypes.musicName = "MainMenuSong.wav";
        bgMusic.Play();
    }
```

Can someone tell me what I`m doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a **`sounds`** folder to the project then pop your music in there and set its **`Copy to Output`** property to **`Copy`**. This will copy it down to the output folder for you.